# white-space:'nowrap' in a table cell breaks the table-layout:'auto': how to fix it?

Tags: html, css, html-table, truncate

I'm trying to design a music playlist : https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xLYLvd

My base element is an HTML table.

I use

```
table-layout:auto;
```

For my table because I want cells to fit their content; as I don't always know how long they will be (especially the last two columns of this example, **.wpsstm-track-actions** and **.wpsstm-track-sources**, where the number of items will vary).

I have 3 columns (the track informations) that I would like to truncate (those are the track artist, title and album cells; which have the **.wpsstm-track-info** class) because I would like to maintain each row on a single text line.

But using

```
white-space: nowrap;
```

on those cells, my design breaks : it seems that *table-layout:auto* and *white-space:nowrap* can't be used together (see line #49 of the pen)

Any ideas on how to succeed on this ?  Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

`text-overflow: ellipsis` only works with `table-layout: fixed`

Also, you need to set a width to the table and apply the text-overflow to the td, not the span inside it.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xLYPBK

You're gonna have to set a static width for **.wpsstm-track-actions** and **.wpsstm-track-sources**, I'm afraid. But that really should be no problem from the design perspective.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply.  That's what I was afraid of... As you can see,  in your example; the album columns now takes some width while it has empty content - that's the kind of stuff I would like to avoid - table-layout:auto was perfect for it.  I know I could deal with this problem using Javascript, but I would prefer a pure CSS solution...

Comment: I know ;_; Have been struggling with this too. If you happen to find a solution, let me know. The only pure css solution would be to wrap the text into a div with position:absolute. But then there wont be the ellipsis effect...